# How can I apply ffdf to non-atomic data frames?

Tags: r, dataframe, bigdata

Many posts ([such as this](http://www.r-bloggers.com/if-you-are-into-large-data-and-work-a-lot-with-package-ff/)) claim the `ff` package is superior to `bigmemory` because it can handle objects w/ atomic and nonatomic components, but how? For example:

```
UNIT <- c(100,100, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 300, 300, 300,300)
STATUS <- c('ACTIVE','INACTIVE','ACTIVE','ACTIVE','INACTIVE','ACTIVE','INACTIVE','ACTIVE',
        'ACTIVE','ACTIVE','INACTIVE') 
TERMINATED <- as.Date(c('1999-07-06','2008-12-05','2000-08-18','2000-08-18','2000-08-18',
                    '2008-08-18','2008-08-18','2006-09-19','2006-09-19','2006-09-19',
                    '1999-03-15')) 
START <- as.Date(c('2007-04-23','2008-12-06','2004-06-01','2007-02-01','2008-04-19',
               '2010-11-29','2010-12-30','2007-10-29','2008-02-05','2008-06-30',
               '2009-02-07'))
STOP <- as.Date(c('2008-12-05','2012-12-31','2007-01-31','2008-04-18','2010-11-28',
              '2010-12-29','2012-12-31','2008-02-04','2008-06-29','2009-02-06',
              '2012-12-31'))
TEST <- data.frame(UNIT,STATUS,TERMINATED,START,STOP)
TEST                   

#install.packages('ff')            
library('ff')            
TEST2 <- ffdf(TEST)            
Error in ffdf(TEST) : ffdf components must be atomic ff objects
```

What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using

```
TEST2 <- as.ffdf(TEST)
```

instead of

```
TEST2 <- ffdf(TEST)
```

will work.

Explanation:
`as.ffdf` converts your data.frame to an ffdf.
If you really want to use `ffdf` directly, you need to supply atomic ff vectors as the error message indicates. For the above example this would be

```
ffdf(UNIT = as.ff(UNIT), STATUS = as.ff(as.factor(STATUS)), TERMINATED = as.ff(TERMINATED), START = as.ff(START), STOP = as.ff(STOP))
```

See ?as.ffdf or ?ffdf, part of the ff package.

In real life, your data would be coming from other sources like csv or SQL sources instead of from a data.frame already in R. See package [ETLUtils](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ETLUtils/index.html) to get your data from SQL into ff easily.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to coerce the columns of TEST data.frame to `ff` objects before the call to `ffdf` but this don't work. Here a workaround using `read.csv.ffdf`:

```
write.csv(TEST,file='test.csv')
TEST.ffd <- read.csv.ffdf(file='test.csv')
```