# convert data.frame to ff

Tags: r, bigdata

I would like to convert a data.frame to a ff object, with as.ffdf as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15787221/how-can-i-apply-ffdf-to-non-atomic-data-frames)

```
df.apr=as.data.frame(df.apr) # from data.table to data.frame
cols=df.apr[1,] 
cols=sapply(cols,class)
df_apr=as.ffdf(df.apr,vmode=cols)
```

gives an error:

```
Error in ff(initdata = initdata, length = length, levels = levels, ordered = ordered,
: vmode 'numeric' not implemented
```

without the 'vmode' argument, the following error is given:

```
Error in ff(initdata = initdata, length = length, levels = levels, ordered = ordered, 
: vmode 'character' not implemented
```

writing away to a table and then reading directly into ff works however:

```
write.table(df.apr,file='df_apr.txt',sep='\t',row.names=F)
df.apr.ff=read.table.ffdf(file='df_apr.txt',header=F,VERBOSE=T)
```

but this is time consuming [and clumsy]. 
is there a better way?

Comment: Hard to help you without data, can you `dput(head(df.apr))`?, also did you test ffdf(ffdf(col1 = as.ff(col1),...) as suggested in the link..? I mean the explanation of @wijffels

Comment: Data is from GDELT, http://gdelt.utdallas.edu/. these daily updates from april are already +/- 0.9 M records. Data.table blows up on this linux debian 64 bit machine with 16 GB RAM [RStudio quits without saying goodbye]. I can do dput(head(df.apr)), and it gives a verbose description of the 58 variables that I expected. did not try the 1 by 1 approach as the workaround is faster/less cumbersome [write to file and read back as ffdf].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to know all possible vmodes which can be used in ff type the following at the console.

```
require(ff)
.vimplemented
```

You'll see that numeric and character modes are not in these. Numerics are converted to doubles, characters to factors. So in your question, you really don't need to specify the vmodes yourself. As long as the characters are coded as factors, you can use as.ffdf on your data.frame. So this will work.

```
df.apr=as.data.frame(df.apr, stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
df_apr=as.ffdf(df.apr)
```

FYI. If your data is coming from flat files, consider using read.table.ffdf or if it is coming from an SQL data source, you can used read.dbi.ffdf or read.odbc.ffdf from the ETLUtils package. If it is coming from Hadoop through Hive, you can use read.jdbc.ffdf from the ETLUtils package.

Comment: I would hope that ffdf will include more modes soon. Sometimes it can be really annoying